# Кросс доменые запросы на AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Вопрос состоит в том, что на многих сайтах пересмотрел кучу информации по поводу кросс-доменного запроса, где-то пишут что это невозможно, где-то, что с недавних пор это стало возможным.
Пожалуйста помогите нужно такое:
сделать запрос на чужой сайт
прочитать там значение скрипта или divа
и вернуть мне значения, но это нужно сделать от ip пользователя.
Пробовал на PHP но там идет от ip сервера а мне так не нужно.

Comment: гуглить в сторону JSONP, а использовать проще с jquery

Comment: Искал но что то не то ,толи я ввиду не знаний не понял толи не то  находил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно производить :) Сам задался этим вопросом когда мне потребовалось выводить актуальную информацию из одного сайта во втором :))) При этом у первого и у второго никакого API не было :)))

Вобщем, структура такова:

1. Создаем функцию **callback**. Пример :

   function callback(data){
       if(data) CheckTheme.success(data);
       else  CheckTheme.error();
   }
2. Далее, нам необходимо создать примерно такой объект:

   ```
   var CheckTheme = {

   link:       'mylink.ru',
   check: function() {
       jQuery.getJSON(this.link+'hw.php?callback=?', {
           param1: "myparam1", //Для передачи методом GET
           param2: "myparam2"
       })
   },
   success: function(j) {
       alert(j);
   },
   error: function () {
       alert("Fucking ajax error");
   }
   ```

   }

Далее, все просто:
При каком-либо событии, нам необходимо вызывать "CheckTheme.check();"
Если в обрутку придет что-то вроде

> callback(/*.........*/);

, то вызовется функция callback, которая потянет за собюой функцию CheckTheme.success(j).

P.S. минимально что должно притопать от сервера:

```
echo  'callback("Hello,World");';
```

Comment: то биш сервер должен в ответе отдавать функцию с аргументами?) и почему $.getJSON? ведь ответ text. да и что вызвался этот коллбэк который пришел из текстового ответа нужно использовать eval а это небезопасно, тем более в данном случае.

Comment: вы-бы прочитали вопрос, что-ли.... "сделать запрос на чужой сайт".... Часто-ли вы можете сделать callback с чужого сайта?

Comment: Я читал вопрос и прекрасно изложил то, что необходимо сделать чтобы он заработал.

со стороннего сервера должен придти ответ:
echo  'callback("Hello,World");';

Если у Вас в функции callback(j) будет выполнение, например, alert(j);, то при выполнении ajax-запроса, в котором вернется текст "callback("Hello,World")" - Вы увидите alert ("Hello World").

Борис, в ответ я должен всего-то послать название функции с аргументами, которая, собвтвенно, должна будет выполнится у клиента.


Безопасность ? Нутк проверяй что там приходит и обезопась себя этим :)

Comment: Спасибо всем буду пробовать,может что и выйдет.

Comment: сторонний сервер - на то и сторонний, что его нельзя заставить вернуть 'callback("Hello,World");'

Answer (score 0):

Запрос можно ( фреймом например ), а вот доступ к содержимому - вроде нет....

UPD: Можно ( запрашивая через `<script>|<style>` ) получить содержимое, но в виде текста, а не DOM - дерева... Ну и ограничение на get запрос....

Answer (score 0):

Система безопасности запрещает производить `AJAX`-запросы между доменами. Надо искать другие пути.